# Find $X_n$ and $X$, $X_n \xrightarrow{\text{d}} X$ with $X_n$ integrable but $X$ not.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, examples-counterexamples, weak-convergence

I need to find examples for a series of random variables $\left(X_n\right)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ and $X$, with $X_n \xrightarrow{\text{d}} X$ and one of the following

1. all $X_n$ integrable but $X$ not,
2. all $X_n$ non-integrable , but $X$ is.

I know that integrable means that the integral over the absolute value isn't $\infty$ and that convergence in distribution is equivalent to $F_{X_n}\to F_X$, but I fail to find integrable distribution functions $f_n$ whose integral from $-\infty$ to $x$ converges to $\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt$ with $f(t)$ not integrable. (such $f_n$ and $f$ would fulfill the first case I think).

Does anyone have some ideas or tipps on how to find examples? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

1. Consider $X_n=X\cdot \mathbf 1\left\{-n\leqslant X\leqslant n\right\}$, where $\mathbf 1$ denotes the indicator function and $X$ is a non-integrable random variable (for example, if $X$ has a [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution)). The convergence is sure hence in probability hence in distribution.
2. Consider $X_n=Y/n$, where $Y$ is a non-integrable random variable. Then $X_n\to 0$ surely hence in probability hence in distribution.

Comment: ok I understand the first one, but how would a non integrable random variable look like? Musn't the integral always be 1 or it wouldn't be a random variable?
And could you further explain for 2. why $X_n$ becomes integrable? (thanks for the answer by the way)

Comment: For 1: there are a lot of examples of non-integrable random variable, for example, Cauchy distributed ones. For 2.: the $X_n$ does not become integrable (for each $n$, $X_n$ is not integrable) but they converge to $0$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo excuse me if it's a bit off-topic, but I've noticed you're very well-versed in probability theory. What references do you recommend so I can reach your level of mastery ?